# Inequality based on location of roots

Tags: quadratics

(a) Find all values of the parameter "k' for which the solution set of the inequation $x^{2}+3 k^{2}-1 \geq 2 k(2 x-1)$ is a subset of the solution set of the inequation $x^{2}-(2 x-1) k+k^{2} \geq 0$

(b) Find all values of k for which there is at least one common solution of the inequalities $x^{2}+4 k x+3 k^{2}>1+2 k$ and $x^{2}+2 k x \leq 3 k^{2}-8 k+4$

(c) Find all values of "k' for which any real x is a solution of at least one of the inequalities $x^{2}+5 k^{2}+8 k>2(3 k x+2)$ and $x^{2}+4 k^{2} \geq k(4 x+1)$

I have these three questions I haven't faced before.

Is there a way to get around these questions with ease? Kindly help me in solving these questions.

Comment: Are you finding difficulty in finding the inequalities or in solving them?

Comment: Finding the inequalities in k.